# How to combine these two arrays in one foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

How to combine the two arrays below? The first prints IDs and the second prints NAMES. What I have now is all IDs printed first and then it continues with all NAMES.

Comment: Combine them... how? What's the relationship between them.

Comment: @Hamish Both arrays have equal objects and have same/correct sorting

Comment: "Equal objects"? Could you provide examples. Make it easy to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use var_dump to see the contents of data. And post the contents here, you're accessing $data incorrectly.

```
$newArray = array_combine($diff, $pages_name['data']);

foreach ($newArray as $data) {
   var_dump($data);
   exit('zzzzz');
   echo $data . '<br>';
}
```

You could also consider using implode : http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
echo implode($newArray, '<br />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_combine()

```
$newArray = array_combine($ids, $values;)
```

Comment: This is what I did but I get printed just *Array* as many times as the objects ( i mean it is correct)  `$newArray = array_combine($diff, $pages_names['data']);

foreach ($newArray as $data){
  echo $data,'<br>';
}`

Comment: @Kaoukkos, use foreach($newArary as $df => $dt) {}, $df will hold values from $diff, and $dt from the other